# Component ratings amps or watts?

Tags: power, current

Why are some DC components rated for maximum amps (LEDs, incandescent lamps, etc.) while other components are rated for maximum watts (resistors, speakers)?

Comment: Speakers are not DC components. Many incandescent lamps run on AC and many resistors are used on DC. Your question is confusing.

Comment: In my experience, incandescent lamps are (were) always rated in watts.

Comment: @PeterBennett Incandescent lamps used on AC mains supplies were typically marked with their operating voltage and power rating but incandescent lamps used on low voltage DC supplies (e.g. torch/flashlight/bicycle lighting) are marked with voltage and current consumption.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Typically, and one can only speak of typically...

**Parts rated for DC current have an expected operating DC voltage or inherent voltage drop across them.** Although they may be able to vary the applied/dropped voltage, they are rated with typical operating voltages so the manufacturer can show typical application characteristics.

**Parts rated by DC power normally operate from a varying DC voltage.** From your examples, resistor applications can have a varying voltage applied to them and speakers will have a varying DC voltage.

So the choice of rating by current or power is on what is most useful to the application circuit designer and to the manufacturer for qualification/production tests.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is not always the case. But most of the time, when you think of **the main purpose** of a particular device, it becomes easier to find an answer.

From your examples, let's start with LEDs.

An **LED's main purpose is lighting**. And the measure of this purpose is **luminous intensity** which is given in Lumens. This parameter is meaningful for different **forward currents** because there's an almost linear relationship between them. Of course the maximum power dissipation is an important parameter but this is considered as a limiting factor for the designer. ***NOTE**: Today, most of the design engineers of consumer lighting industry select LEDs based on the wattages for white light. That's because the consumers rate some lighting products with their wattages rather than the lighting-related parameters. This pushes the designers to think about wattage of the LEDs during design process.*

Now let's continue with speakers.

**The main purpose is to generate sound**. And the measure of this purpose is **sound intensity** which is given in decibels (dB). This parameter is meaningful for different **power levels** applied to the speaker. Of course the maximum current is an important parameter due to the existence of windings, but this parameter is taken into account when the range of RMS voltage across the speaker is known (i.e. the guaranteed maximum RMS output voltage of a power amplifier).

Finally, resistors.

We can't say a particular purpose but whatever they are used for, the power is always the 2nd parameter (1st is resistance, of course) to consider because the voltage across them or the current flowing through them is never a constant, known parameter.

However... This does not apply to very low resistances (e.g. current sense resistors) since they are rated for maximum allowed current. Also, for **SMD** resistors, the maximum terminal voltage is always a parameter for choice. For example, you can't randomly put a 470k/125mW 0805 case SMD resistor across a 230Vac just because its power level is sufficient, because the maximum allowed terminal voltage is not higher than 150V for most of those resistors.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

*Figure 1. A selection of coloured LEDs. Image source: [LED Supply](https://www.ledsupply.com/blog/how-does-a-5mm-led-work/).*

These LEDs all have different forward voltages for a given current. This means that the power consumption (watts) will vary with the colour. LEDs are current controlled devices so it makes sense to rate them by current.

[image]

*Figure 2. Typical IV curves for various colours of LEDs. Image source: [LEDnique](http://lednique.com/current-voltage-relationships/iv-curves/).*

[image]

*Figure 3. A selection of 1/4 W resistors. Image source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resistor).*

These resistors are all capable of dissipating 1/4 W. If they were to be rated by current then the E12 series from 1 Ω to 10 MΩ would have 85 entries for the current ratings. i.e., a separate rating for each resistor. It makes far more sense to use the power rating which is common for the full series.